# Show that $X_n\to^P X$ in probability as $n\to \infty$.

Tags: probability, inequality

I try to prove the following statement:

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $X_n=X+Y_n$, where $E[Y_n]=\frac{1}{n}$ and $Var[Y_n]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and $\sigma>0$. Show that $X_n\stackrel P\to X$ in probability as $n\to \infty$.

---

I am not sure if my proof works:

It is enough to show that $Y_n\stackrel P\to 0$. Since for every $\epsilon>0$, by Markov inequality,
$$
P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)\le \frac{E|Y_n|^2}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{\sigma^2}{n})\to 0
$$

Comment: $\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 \le E(X^2)$

Comment: @WeakLearner Thanks. Is there other method to prove that?

Comment: Your edited version now shows $Y_n  \xrightarrow{p} Y$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @Henry What's $Y$?

Comment: @Hermi Your proof by Markov's inequality looks good to me

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thanks.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio $Y=0$ but I was typing too quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$
P(|Y_n| > \varepsilon) < P(|Y_n-EY_n| > \varepsilon/2) + P(|EY_n|> \varepsilon/2)\tag{0}
$$
by the triangle inequality. Then note that
$$
P(|Y_n-EY_n| > \varepsilon/2)\le\frac{Var(Y_n)}{(\varepsilon/2)^2} \to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ by Chebyshev's inequality, so
$$
P(|EY_n| > \varepsilon/2) =1_{|EY_n| > \varepsilon/2}=0
$$
for large $n$, since $EY_n\to0$.

Comment: Thank you! But how about my edited proof? Dose it work now?